# Permission issue with Gmailapp

Tags: permissions, google-apps-script, gmail

I've been trying to follow [this guide](http://www.pipetree.com/qmacro/blog/2011/10/automated-email-to-task-mechanism-with-google-apps-script/) to automate filing of tasks.

However, my Google Apps Script trips up at the following:

```
var label_pending = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(LABEL_PENDING);
```

When I run the script, I get a continuous loop of pop-up saying "Authorization Required": the pop-up reappears right after I continue and accept. If I cancel, I get the following error:

```
Execution failed: Authorization is required to perform that action.
```

Does anyone know how to bypass this issue ?

Comment: Does the authorization popup ask for authorization for the right account ? are you logged with multiple account ? do you run the function from a menu or from the script editor ? have you tried to write another test function like GmailApp.sendEmail('anAdress@gmail.com,'test','test') ?

Comment: Yup, it asks authorization for the right account; nope I'm not logged into multiple accounts; I've tried both running from Google docs menu (Tools -> script manager... -> run) and from the script editor. If I run from the menu, it will ask for permission once and then not execute anything after that. I tried writing a test function that only calls GmailApp.createLabel("test"); - this runs into the same issue

Comment: hmmm...if you're really sure then try maybe on a different account... so you are not even able to send a simple email using script ? If so go to the issue tracker giving the script ID of a simple test script for Googlers to check it.